# How can I triage a discrepancy between my df and du output?

Tags: disk-usage

**NOTE:** I'm fully aware of these other questions on this site:

- [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage)
- [du on ramdisk displays 3GB less than df](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101818/du-on-ramdisk-displays-3gb-less-than-df)

My issue shows up as follows:

```
$ du -sh / --exclude=/proc
4.0G    /
```

vs.

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_root   18G 16.0G  1.9G  90% /
devtmpfs                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      3.9G   39M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                      3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                  497M  215M  283M  44% /boot
tmpfs                      783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/937000511
tmpfs                      783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/937000593
```

How can I triage this issue to determine what's causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Also (helpful tips "buried" in the Question itself) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19425/how-can-i-diagnose-and-repair-missing-drive-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case the problem was a daemon running which had its files rotated via `logrotate` but the service wasn't sent a `kill -HUP` to trigger it to start logging to a new file. This resulted in a 12G log file continuing to show up as though it were consuming space on the HDD which was visible via `df` but not `du`, given how both of these CLI tools work.

#### lsof

Using `lsof` and looking for the log file showed the issue:

```
$ lsof | grep -E 'COMMAND|/var/log/maxscale'
COMMAND     PID   TID           USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
maxscale   5976             maxscale  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
maxscale   5976             maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)
maxscale   5976  5977       maxscale  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
maxscale   5976  5977       maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)
maxscale   5976  5978       maxscale  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
maxscale   5976  5978       maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)
maxscale   5976  5979       maxscale  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
maxscale   5976  5979       maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)
maxscale   5976  5980       maxscale  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
maxscale   5976  5980       maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)
MHD-singl  5976  5981       maxscale  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
MHD-singl  5976  5981       maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)
bash      12629                 root  cwd       DIR              253,1        4096      82757 /var/log/maxscale
```

The `lsof` output even shows the size in question and that it was in fact deleted:

> maxscale   5976             maxscale    4w      REG              253,1 12506246848      82752 /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log (deleted)

Stopping the daemon released/closed the file descriptor freeing the space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_root   18G  4.0G   14G  23% /
devtmpfs                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      3.9G   39M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                      3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                  497M  215M  283M  44% /boot
tmpfs                      783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/937000511
tmpfs                      783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/937000593
```

Now `df` and `du` are in agreement.